# AIX and .nfs impossible to remove until slibclean

Tags: shared-libraries, aix, nfs, rm

I'm facing a problem under AIX specificaly.
I've got a process that deploys a jdk in a directory, use it and then remove the directory, this on a NFS filesystem.

AIX has this behaviour that it keeps shared libraries in memory even if they are no more used. I'm then unable to remove the java directory because it create the well known .nfs_xxxxxx files.

The only way if found to be able to remove the library is to remove the no more used library from memory using the command "slibclean".

The problem is this command has to be run as root user, that is not a good solution in my case.

My question is : is there an equivalent of slibclean for a normal user, or is there a way to tell AIX to not keep unused shared library in memory ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, could you please explain these well known .nfs files? (I know slibclean, but never used NFS). You cannot delete these files because some shared libraries are still lingering in the memory? What error-code / error-message are you getting?

Comment: Hi. I will not be able to explain better than the answer in this post :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231074/removed-a-vagrant-file-and-now-i-see-nfs0000000000b869e300000001

Comment: Well, how are these files related to unused shared objects lingering in memory? (BTW: what shared objects are these? Java runtime?)

Comment: In my case those are java libraries. I can check it with the genkld command. Per example genkld will return this line (amoung lots of others):
>genkld |grep libhythr.so
900000002a74000     2955 .../lib/ppc64/compressedrefs/libhythr.so
This correspond to a java library of a java that i do not use anymore

Comment: That's okay, genkld, genld, procldd etc are meant to examine the shared-library usage. What do these shared libs have to do with un-deletable NFS-files?

Comment: The .nfs is created when i delete the library file. It kind of replace the library file. And if a delete the .nfs, another one is created. So an rm -rf on a directory containing this library will never end

Comment: Oh I see, you have an AIX-computer as NFS-client, where you periodically install and uninstall JRE (or JDK). As non-root user. Well, I have no idea what to do. (Other than install JRE (or JDK) onto local disk. Once. As root-user.)